# Yolov5 custom object detection model not loading

Tags: opencv, object-detection, yolov5

I have a trained a custom object detection model using yolov5 for 4 classes. I have downloaded the best.pt file. I am still confused about how to load this model using pytorch.
I tried running the following code to load the model as per Yolov5 official documentation
`model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='best.pt')` 
but when I tried printing model.names, I am not getting my custom class names. Is there anything I am missing?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try clearing your cache by adding this: `force_reload=True`
2. Store your model in a local folder called model (in case you are locally
   trying to run this)

**then try adding this**:

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='model/best-m.pt', force_reload=True)
```